# Shell script to send a mail once every 20 days

Tags: shell-script

Need a shell script to be called via cron job every day and see if it's 20th day,it should send a mail

Answer (score 0):

You could always do (assuming GNU `date` and `bash`/`ksh93`/`zsh`):

```
o=$(date +%::z)
o=${o:0:1}$((10#${o:1:2} * 3600 + 10#${o:4:2} * 60 + 10#${o:7}))
[ "$((($(date +%s) $o) /(24*60*60) % 20))" -eq 0 ] || exit
mailx -s subject recipient@seebyte.com << EOM
Hiya
EOM
```

The idea being to count the number of days since 1970-01-01 (the first part to get and apply the UTC offset), and exit unless that number is a multiple of 20.